# how to create object for map function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

trying to build the object that has key/value pair for map function that is defined in interface but it throws below error. what is correct object needed here `queryString` based on interface that does not throw type error.

interface.ts

```
export interface IStringName {
    QueryString ? : Map < string, string > ;
}
```

main.ts

```
const queryString: QueryString = {
    stringList: "registration"
};


if (queryString && queryString.keys.length > 0) {
    let queryStr: string = "?";

    queryString.forEach((value, key) => {
        queryStr += key + "=" + value + "&";
    });

    Config.Url += "/" + queryStr.substr(0, queryStr.length - 1)
}
```

Error

```
stringList is not assignable to type map, string, string >
```

Comment: what is QueryString?

Comment: queryString is how i will get the object from the service as req.body

Comment: any chance you can say what library do you use?

It's unclear if queryString is just a javascript object `{}` or if it's an es6 `Map`.
If it's a map, the way you assign value in the example you put here is incorrect. If it's a javascript object, the `forEach` loop is wrong.

Comment: You use it as type what is the type of it `const queryString: QueryString = ..`

Comment: i am using typescript and type would be map function as it is declared in interface